# dev cpp Save and open files with same encoding format

Tags: encoding, dev-c++

I wrote the code in the visual studio code with utf-8 like this

```
cout << "你好，世界！" << endl;
```

But with dev-c++ open the file Chinese will become another way like this

```
cout << "��ã����磡" << endl;
```

Is there any way for them to open the file in the same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that currently Dev-C++ does not support UTF-8 encoding, as seen in [this ticket from 2016](https://sourceforge.net/p/orwelldevcpp/tickets/161/). The discussion there points to [this link](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.de/2013/10/dev-c-552-released.html#c5070352981113486769) where someone said in 2013:

> Currently, it is not possible to read or write UTF-8 files using Dev-C++. Sorry about that.
>   At the moment, there are no plans to support non-ANSI encodings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I had to change a compiler.